# Adding Service and Version to custom stackdriver trace api

Tags: trace, stackdriver, google-cloud-platform

I am using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/tree/master/trace to send custom traces to Stackdriver Trace from GCP. All these traces end up without a service or version. How do you add that information using the trace api ?

Is there a way to add the serviceContext in `trace.NewClient` or the span ?

EDIT : 
The first answer helps but the Stackdriver UI does not show these unless they are GAE( or internal apps). Mine is a standlone Go app.

[stackdriver ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngVWS.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add these two labels to the span you're creating:

trace.cloud.google.com/gae/app/module
trace.cloud.google.com/gae/app/version

Comment: Thanks. That does get end up in the trace info. Unfortunately, the stackdriver UI probably only gets these version from the internal services.

Comment: I think this should work.  Can you post the code you're using to post these?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem, here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    span := tc.SpanFromRequest(r)
    span.SetLabel("trace.cloud.google.com/gae/app/module", "my-service")
    span.SetLabel("trace.cloud.google.com/gae/app/version", "v0.1")
    defer span.Finish()
```

The dashboard shows me the correct service and version when I look at the span details, but I cannot filter by service/version, exactly as described in the original question.

Thoughts?